# Google indexing multiple subdomains IIS server

Tags: seo, indexing, iis-6, subdomain

Having answered a few questions on StackOverflow, I'm excited to be asking my first one!

We've just discovered that Google is not only indexing our website at www., but also URLs from the website at mx1., 2., wwww., ww., nc. and httpwww.  Clearly this isn't good news, as Google will think these are duplicate pages.

People suggest that this means that our website is allowing wildcard subdomains, but from what I understand IIS doesn't allow wildcard subdomains.  We're using Windows Server 2003, which I think means IIS 6.  We host our own website.

Does anyone know why this has happened, and how to stop it happening in the future?  I understand that Bing isn't indexing these subdomains.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS does allow wildcard domains.

Add some code in your Application_BeginRequest where you analyze the Request.Host and redirect appropriately. And remove wildcard DNS. Just leave"www" and "".

Comment: Apologies for the long delay in replying.  Can this be done without any script, just using the UI of IIS?  I've no idea how to implement the solution you request.  Failing that, do you have a few clues as to where to start?  I know ASP.NET, VB and SQL, if that helps.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this in the UI. You need to add a few lines to Application_BeginRequest to do the redirect yourself. Look on Google to see how you get the host and do a redirect.

Comment: Thanks - will try it when I get a chance.